# online symbolic math tool for simplifying an expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have an algebraic expression containing exp(t) and powers of t. I want to group the like terms to simplify the appearance of the expression. Is there any online tool for this?

Comment: Try the [online version of Mathematica](https://lab.open.wolframcloud.com/app/)

Comment: Try http://www.wolframalpha.com/.

Comment: Or http://octave-online.net/ if you are familiar with MATLAB's Symbolic Toolbox.